# Loading CLR dll from Native code

Tags: c++, clr, native, loadlibrary

I am trying to use the following code:

`LoadLibraryExA(filename.c_str(), NULL, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES);`

To load a C++\CLR dll from a native assembly.
The `HMODULE` returned is `NULL` and the `GetLastError` returns - `193` which means `is not a valid win32 application`

How can I load the library correctly? What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!
Ron

Comment: What do you want to do with the DLL once you've loaded it? You are aware that you cannot treat it as an unmanaged DLL?

Comment: What do you mean by 'treating as unmanaged DLL'. The dll have a singleton class that I want to use (it is declared without 'ref', so as I know - it is native.. ?)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a mixed mode DLL as your comments indicate, then the usual explanation for `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT` is that the bitness of the host process does not match the bitness of the DLL. You are trying to load a 32 bit DLL into a 64 bit process, or vice versa.

If you have matching bitness then the most likely explanation is that the DLL is a managed DLL rather than a mixed mode DLL.

Comment: The host and the CLR dll are both configured for platform - "win32"

Comment: I guess the DLL is not mixed mode then. In any case, how are you going to import a class from the DLL? You need load time linking I think.

Comment: How do i configure it as 'mixed-mode'?